# What is meant by the comma in the Chinese Wiktionary terms?

Tags: word

I am browsing the wiktionary data for the Chinese terms, and found [一子失著，滿盤皆輸](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E5%AD%90%E5%A4%B1%E8%91%97%EF%BC%8C%E6%BB%BF%E7%9B%A4%E7%9A%86%E8%BC%B8#Chinese). What does that mean, is that two words that have the same definition? Or some sort of orthographic thing I am not aware of for representing more complex concepts?

> - (Pinyin): yī zǐ shīzhāo, mǎnpán jiē shū
> - (Zhuyin): ㄧ ㄗˇ ㄕ ㄓㄠ, ㄇㄢˇ ㄆㄢˊ ㄐㄧㄝ ㄕㄨ

I see there is both a simplified and traditional form of that whole sequence of characters, so it's not that. How does this work, what role does the comma play and is this one single word or multiple synonyms? If it's one word, please explain how the comma gets used in these types of situations.

Answer (score 1):

一子失著 and 滿盤皆輸 are two independent phrases, "one mistaken step (in chess play)" and "losing the whole game", combined, it calls for acting prudently.

https://dict.idioms.moe.edu.tw/idiomView.jsp?ID=18913&webMd=1&la=0

https://zhonghuachengyu.18dao.net/%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E6%88%90%E8%AA%9E/%E4%B8%80%E5%AD%90%E5%A4%B1%E8%91%97%EF%BC%8C%E6%BB%BF%E7%9B%A4%E7%9A%86%E8%BC%B8

Comment: Are they supposed to be used and written with the comma and all 8 characters divided in half? Or are you supposed to use half at a time, no comma?

Comment: It is usually with a comma in between to indicate this is a two phrases idiom and how to read properly.

Comment: No, you cannot use just half of the whole sentence. It is actually saying that IF 一子失著, THEN 滿盤皆輸.

Comment: @PdotWang Not necessarily, each phrase has a complete meaning, so they can be separated to make a sentence - 我因**一子失著**, 導致**滿盤皆輸** = 我**滿盤皆輸**的原因是**一子失著**.